# Twig variables in twig variable

Tags: twig

I have a twig variable **html**. To show it in a twig template I do `{{html}}`.

That variable looks like:

`<div>{{region_top}}</div><div>{{region_center}}</div>`

`region_*` is a variable too. When Twig parses my `html` variable, it doesn't parse the inner variables (regions).

What I should do?

Comment: At first accept answers to your previous questions…

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I have twig variable html. To show it in twig template I do {{html}}. That variable look like {{region_top}}{{region_center}}. region_* is variables too. When twig parse my html variable he didn't parse inner variables (regions). What can I should do?

Twig takes your strings as a literal string, meaning you'll see the content of the variable, escaped. If you want it to be able to display {{region_top}} as well, I'd recommend something like this:

```
{{html|replace({'{{region_top}}': region_top, '{{region_center}}': region_center})}}
```

If the content of your html variable is also dynamic (meaning it can contain more than just those two variables), I'd write a twig plugin which can do what you want. Writing plugins is pretty easy to do.

**EDIT**: Here's the extension I just finished writing.

**EDIT 2**: The extension now uses the environment to render the string, so it evaluates the string, instead of just replacing variables. This means your variable can contain anything a template can, and it will be render and escaped by Twig itself. I'm awesome.

```php
<?php

/**
* A twig extension that will add an "evaluate" filter, for dynamic evaluation.
*/
class EvaluateExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
    /**
    * Attaches the innervars filter to the Twig Environment.
    * 
    * @return array
    */
    public function getFilters( ) {
        return array(
            'evaluate' => new \Twig_Filter_Method( $this, 'evaluate', array(
                'needs_environment' => true,
                'needs_context' => true,
                'is_safe' => array(
                    'evaluate' => true
                )
            ))
        );
    }

    /**
     * This function will evaluate $string through the $environment, and return its results.
     * 
     * @param array $context
     * @param string $string 
     */
    public function evaluate( \Twig_Environment $environment, $context, $string ) {
        $loader = $environment->getLoader( );

        $parsed = $this->parseString( $environment, $context, $string );

        $environment->setLoader( $loader );
        return $parsed;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the parser for the environment to Twig_Loader_String, and parsed the string $string.
     * 
     * @param \Twig_Environment $environment
     * @param array $context
     * @param string $string
     * @return string 
     */
    protected function parseString( \Twig_Environment $environment, $context, $string ) {
        $environment->setLoader( new \Twig_Loader_String( ) );
        return $environment->render( $string, $context );
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of this extension.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName( ) {
        return 'evaluate';
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```php
$twig_environment->addExtension( new EvaluateExtension( ) );
```

In the template:

```
{% set var = 'inner variable' %}
{{'this is a string with an {{var}}'|evaluate}}
```

Comment: Maybe replace filter can use such as preg_replace with placeholder? Something like this {{html|replace({'{{$1}}': $1})}} I have no idea what plugin should do :(

Comment: @Meliborn I meant an extension. I've just checked, but it seems I'm not able to get a hold of the value of a variable from an extension, oddly enough. I'll keep looking: I might need something like this myself.

Comment: @Meliborn Just added an extension that does what you want it to do :)

Comment: @Meliborn Just updated the extension: it now uses the environment to parse the string, so you get all benefits you would in a normal template.

Comment: Awesome, but how to disable autoescape? raw filter and auto escape expression didn't work:( Maybe it's problem with render() method in your extension?

Comment: @Meliborn Odd, you seem to be right. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: Now, it's escaped inner variables (region_*) :)

Comment: @Meliborn When I use `{% set foo = '<script>alert("foo")</script>' %}` and `{{'This is a string {{foo|raw}}'|evaluate}}`, it will alert foo, so the behaviour is the same as twig itself.

Comment: Thanks for the Extension, it works great! Defining it as a service globally makes it possible to use it in every controller from then! 
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: How do I chain raw into this ?

Comment: @Berry can you look at my question, its pretty short https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035901/how-to-evaluate-twig-expression

Comment: This is awesome, do you know how to do this with symfony 5 ?

Answer (score 18):

See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html

It seems that this is frequently missed as most folks think (and search for) "eval" when expecting a filter/function to evaluate in the current language they're drafting in.  Template from string isn't the first search query that comes to mind.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to render your templates as strings.  You can do that like this:

```
$env = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String());
echo $env->render(
  "Hello {{ name }}",
  array("name" => "World")
);
```

I'll leave it to you to decide how exactly to structure your code to make this work, but it might go something like this:
1) Fetch the inner template text that contains the variables that aren't being replaced.
2) Render that inner template text into an $html variable.  Be sure to pass in any vars you need.
3) Render your original template that contains {{html}}.  Be sure to pass in 'html' => $html in the vars array

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass an array or an object to the view, and then use the twig attribute() method: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html

```
{% if attribute(array, key) is defined %}
    {{ attribute(array, key) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, nice and simple. Thanks!