# Load view without rendering

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

I have a Twig extension in my Symfony project which renders a twitter widget. Currently, in my extension, I have this:

```
public function twitter($handle, $number = 5)
{
    return "<div data-tweet-row=\"&lt;div&gt;&lt;a  href='http://twitter.com/{screen_name}/status/{id}'&gt;{tweet}&lt;/a&gt;&lt;span class='datetime'&gt;{datetime}&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;\" data-twitter-header=\"&lt;div class='header'&gt;&lt;img src='https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name={screen_name}&amp;size=normal' /&gt;&lt;h4&gt;&lt;a href='http://twitter.com/{screen_name}'&gt;@{screen_name}&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/h4&gt;&lt;/div&gt;\" id=\"twitter\">&nbsp;</div><script>$('#twitter').biff_twitter({screen_name:'$handle',count:$number});</script>";
}
```

However I really don't like this solution, I'd rather have the HTML saved under `views` and then load the file from within my extension.

I have access to the container from within the extension using:

```
private $container;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container){
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

So I need something like

```
$view_file = $this->container->get('...')->view('InternalSocialBundle:twitter_placeholder.html.twig')
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question. You can render the file using `render`. It doesn't mean you have to return a response. Just save the render as a variable. And you can use it wherever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I resolved the issue that I had but it was sort of my fault for not testing this fully. @Cyprian's solution does indeed work absolutely fine when you're not doing anything complicated and just using the extension as intended.

My problem was that I was using this [evaluate extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10945264/475125) which was loading a template from the database, therefore it was twig that was doing all of the loading (and therefore was only interpreting the first param of `$this->render()` as a `string` - it made no attempt to load it using the symfony naming pattern).

This means my extension would work fine when using the above method in an actual twig file, but not when I used the `{{body|evaluate}}` extension.

The solution to this problem was as follows:

In my services.yml file, not only did I need `service_container`, but also `twig.loader` so it looked something liked:

```
class: Test\SocialBundle\Twig\SocialExtension
arguments: [@service_container,@twig.loader]
tags:
    -  { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

I then have this as the twig extensions constructor:

```
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, \Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Loader\FilesystemLoader $loader)
{
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->loader = $loader;
}
```

In my `getFilters()` definition:

```
public function getFilters()
{
  return array(
    'twitter' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'twitter',array(
        'is_safe' => array(
            'evaluate' => true
            ),
        'needs_environment' => true,
        )
    )
  )
}
```

and finally, before I returned the rendered output:

```
public function twitter(\Twig_Environment $environment, $id)
{
    $social_item = array(); // get my data here from my service;
    $environment->setLoader($this->loader);
    return $environment->render("TestSocialBundle:Front:twitter_placeholder.html.twig",array());
}
```

This ensured that I was always using the `\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Loader\FilesystemLoader` loader, and not `\Twig_Loader_String` which was being used in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have totally right. Name of the service you are looking for is `templating`.
So this will work for You:

```
$html = $this->container->get('templating')->render('InternalSocialBundle:twitter_placeholder.html.twig');
```

**edit:**

This is an working example:

```
class FooExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        return $this->container->get('templating')->render('CogiPortfolioBundle:Portfolio:tmp.html.twig');
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'foo' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'foo', array('is_safe' => array('html')))
        );
    }

    /* (...) */
}
```

The service definition:

```
<service id="cogi.foo.ext" class="Cogi\PortfolioBundle\TwigExtension\FooExtension">
    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
    </call>
    <tag name="twig.extension" />
</service>
```

And know if I call in any template {{ foo() }} it renders html from `tmp.twig.html`. And on the other side - if in my extension I put "path" to non existing template in `render` method then an exception is thrown.

I hope this helps.

Comment: When I do this from within my Twig extension I just get the string returned to me, so if I do what you said echo out `$html` and it just gives me `InternalSocialBundle:twitter_placeholder.html.twig`. I have a feeling I'm just going to have to do it from within my service and then pass it back into my Twig extension.

Comment: In fact, if I do an `exists()` on that file it returns `true` and if I change the name to `InternalSpeltWrong:twitter.html.twig` it still returns `true`. Strange.

Comment: If I do `$this->container->get('templating')->render('{{asd}}',array('asd'=>'123asd'));` it outputs `123asd` so it seems that `InternalSocialBundle:twitter_placeholder.html.twig` is just being interpreted as a string and not the file I want to load.

Comment: try use 'renderResponse' method instead of 'render'. This is the way how base symfony 2 controller class works.

Comment: I did try renderResponse but it just gives me http://pastebin.com/UDUa8yCJ when I echo it out. This is an odd issue as it doesn't *look* like I'm doing anything incorrectly..

Comment: after spending hours trying to get this to work, it seems that the naming pattern of Symfony (e.g. `Bundle:A:b.html.twig`) won't work for me when inside a twig extension (I assume it's because it doesn't know about anything apart from twig). I ended up doing a file_get_contents (http://pastebin.com/RDf8TVdi) - it's not a nice solution at all but it'll do for now until I have time to find a proper solution.

Comment: If I have to guess I will tell that is not about naming, because template engine should should throw an exception if there is any problem with template (for example: template doesn't exist). I assume if you put it inside any controller it works, right? Maybe you can check which class is instancing when you get 'templating' service? I've tried the same with some of my extensions and everything went fine... I'll try figure out this at the weekend :)

Comment: Was it a twig extension you created (extending `\Twig_Extension`)? The only thing I can think of is that twig isn't aware of the loading/naming pattern so it just interoperates my file as text and parses that. Strange, I'll install a fresh copy of SF and take a further look. Maybe you could link to a pastebin of your extension code?

Comment: Finally found the answer to this. If you're interested see my post. Essentially, you were right in a normal instance of what I wanted, but in some cases the way I was using my extension, the loader being used was `\Twig_Loader_String`