# twig convert a string to the object that it represent

Tags: symfony, twig

imaging that i have a object and which can be called in a twig template like this:

```
{{ object1.object2.object3.property3A }}
```

well, it will show me the content if we use php to write is :

```
$object1->getObject2()->getObject3()->getProperty3A();
```

My question is if i have a string ,

```
$refString="object1.object2.object3.property3A";
```

and then it is passed to twig, how could i get the property3A? For my experience, we can do this in php like this:

```
$refString="object1->getObject2()->getObject3()->getProperty3A()";
echo $$refString;
```

But i do not know how to make it work in twig.

Comment: It may be possible to do using attribute: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html but not sure how that behaves with multiple calls like yours, you may need to split apart on your dot, then recursively call it.

Comment: yes, i have tried attribute, if you have a property1A, it is easy. but function attribute will not work for the mutiple level.

Comment: Hence the recursion, which you need to do yourself, split the string apart on the first dot, and if the remaining right part has a dot, the recurse again, otherwise, return the attribute using the left side of the dot, and the right in the last loop.

Comment: thanks, i know how to use a recursive function to do this, but it is ugly, and some how in twig do this kind of thing make me feel strange. Well as you say, if out of the attribute function, we do not have other solution, i have to do it in another way, just like treate the table in php, save them in a table then just render the value in twig.

Comment: I don't think recursion is the problem here, but maybe yes, do it in PHP and pass the value to Twig instead. If you don't know how deep the call must be I don't know what else you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't tested this, but i think it schould do the trick.

```
{#
    recursively reading attributes from an object
    ! object1 must be available !
    theValue is the value of property3A
#}
{% for key in "object1.object2.object3.property3A"|split('.') %}
  {% if not loop.first %}{# skip the 'object1' part #}
    {% set theValue = attribute(theValue|default(object1), key) %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "shortcut" to do this in twig. If you can't find a simple way to do this, you can write you own extension, that would convert a STRING_TYPE to a VAR_TYPE.

[Twig internals](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/internals.html) might put you on the right track. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945200/twig-variables-in-twig-variable) is an example of what is feasable with twig extension and might inspire you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation. This answer will only work if the object you need is available to the template and you know the name of it with a string.

In this case, you can access the object using Twig's Global Variable `_context`:

```
{% set object1 = _context['object1'] %}
```

And then access the methods and variables of the object as normal:

```
{{ object1.object2.object3.property3A }}
```