# Passing Assetic image path from database

Tags: php, image, symfony, assetic

I have been stumped for a couple days and I am seeking some direction.

I am attempting to call an image path stored in database to twig file in order to display said image. The twig example below, I am expecting the same image to be displayed twice.  When inspecting the rendered html, the variable passes the path from the database, but the first image is not displayed.

From controller:

```
'logo' => $vendor->getLogovendors()
```

From database column logoVendors:

```
<img src={{asset('bundles/loginlogin/img/fs_logo_large.png')}} />
```

From twig:

```
<div class="container">
  {{logo | raw}}
  <img src={{asset('bundles/loginlogin/img/fs_logo_large.png')}} />
</div>
```

I am new to Symfony and its asset management. Any help or prodding in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you storing ```<img src={{asset('bundles/loginlogin/img/fs_logo_large.png')}} />``` in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normally store only the **path** to the image in your database!

If *logo* was the variable you pass to the template holding the image path `bundles/loginlogin/img/fs_logo_large.png` you could simply include it using twig's asset function like this:

```
 <img src="{{ asset(logo) }}"/>
```

---

what you're trying to do ( evaluating a twig function inside a string ) can be solved aswell...but i don't recommend it.

If you want to store the complete code including `{{ asset() }}` in your database you need to make twig evaluate the code inside the string.

This means twig shall execute the code inside the string instead of just printing it.

This can be achieved using the **evaluate filter** from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945200/twig-variables-in-twig-variable).

The final result would then be:

```
{{ logo |evaluate |raw }}
```

Comment: +1 For the correct answer. Except that path is very brittle. I would go a step (or two, or three) further and only store the file's name and have a known directory structure or at least store just ```img/fs_logo_large.png```

Comment: jeah i was thinking about introducing him to the @-syntax but i wanted to keep the answer short :)

Comment: Yes, you guys are so good.  Thank you so much, you've not just given me a solution but some understanding.  Slainté!

Comment: OK.  I hate to bother, but I'm compelled to ask; not for an explanation just a bit more info.  I follow the logic of 'brittle path' and deduce from your comments there is an even more appropriate method here.(@-syntax)  Again, any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to find any reference to such(@-syntax), but efforts are thus far fruitless.  Just mostly looking for further terminology so I may research for myself.

Comment: Here's a question over at SV that may help you: http://serverfault.com/questions/95444/storing-a-million-images-in-the-filesystem  I'll find some time tomorrow and offer another answer

Comment: Very kind.  The link has given me a great jump-off for further learning.  Thanks for your help.