# Parse a variable content in TWIG

Tags: php, templates, twig, kohana

I have an given template file with following content:

> Welcome, {{ user }}

In my PHP File I load this content by:

```
$welcome = file_get_contents(APPPATH . 'classes/Plugins/Core/testplugin/view/frontend/index.html');
```

So that's in template:

> "Welcome, {{ user }}"

Now, if I give this content into my template:

```
$twig->welcome = $welcome;
$twig->user = "Tom";
```

Template output (html):

> {{ welcome }}

Template output (browser):

> Welcome, {{ user }}

My problem: Template engine won't replace my user given in twig string!

Any ideas? I tried using following filters:

> {{ welcome|nl2br|raw }}

Comment: It looks like your template isn't getting parsed. Where are you calling `$twig->render()`?

Comment: Currently, i think, nowhere. If i only use {{ user }} i have the correct output. It looks like the string value won't accept anything inside..

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10945200/1607098) might be of interest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have a string in your template which [in itself](http://bossip.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/xzibit.png?w=500) is a template. Then you need to tell Twig to treat your template variable as a template, otherwise it'll just treat it as string. For this there's [the `template_from_string` function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html).