# How to include user info in yaml menu in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml

I am currently developping using symfony2 and using FOSUserBundle for user management.

I built a menus.yml config file to separate html from menu structure. Basicaly I import menus.yml in my config.yml file and it's added to twig's global vars. Here's a look at my menus.yml (Abridged version)

```
twig:
globals:
    menus:
        loggedin:
            topleft:
                -
                    path: ~
                    caption: Réseau
                    icon: glyphicon-comment
                    submenu:
                        -
                            path: nouvelles
                            caption: Fil de nouvelles
                            icon: glyphicon-globe
            topright:
                -
                    path: ~
                    caption: "{{ app.user.prenom }} {{ app.user.nom }}"
                    icon: glyphicon-user
```

Then, in my template html file, I render the menu using this

```
{% for m in menus.loggedin.topleft %}
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ m.caption }}</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        {% for item in m.submenu %}
        <li><a href="#">{{item.caption}}</a></li>
        {% if item.seperator is defined and item.seperator == true %}
        <li class="divider"></li>
        {% endif %}    
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

But I am unable to display the user's first name and last name as the textual value gets printed as is into the html page. I tried hooking the app.user into caption like this

```
caption: %app.user.prenom% %app.user.nom%
```

But it doesn't work, saying the value doesn't exist (yet?)

Anybody has a clue how I can work this around?

Comment: Why don't you add `{{ app.user.prenom }} {{ app.user.nom }}` in the Twig template? You can add a condition to test if it's the left or right part.

Comment: I could, but I won't be seperating menu structure from the template. My topright attribute has more items in it, but I've truncated to simplify the yaml example.

Comment: You can try this: [Twig variables in twig variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14943865/2257664).

Comment: Wow nice! I used the evaluate filter from the answer and it works like a charm! Write it as an answer so I can credit you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked for an equivalent of the `eval()` [PHP](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.eval.php) or [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/eval) function in Twig and found this SO question: [Twig variables in twig variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14943865/2257664).

Here is the code from an [answer by Berry Langerak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10945264/2257664) which define a Twig filter:

```
<?php

/**
* A twig extension that will add an "evaluate" filter, for dynamic evaluation.
*/
class EvaluateExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
    /**
    * Attaches the innervars filter to the Twig Environment.
    * 
    * @return array
    */
    public function getFilters( ) {
        return array(
            'evaluate' => new \Twig_Filter_Method( $this, 'evaluate', array(
                'needs_environment' => true,
                'needs_context' => true,
                'is_safe' => array(
                    'evaluate' => true
                )
            ))
        );
    }

    /**
     * This function will evaluate $string through the $environment, and return its results.
     * 
     * @param array $context
     * @param string $string 
     */
    public function evaluate( \Twig_Environment $environment, $context, $string ) {
        $loader = $environment->getLoader( );

        $parsed = $this->parseString( $environment, $context, $string );

        $environment->setLoader( $loader );
        return $parsed;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the parser for the environment to Twig_Loader_String, and parsed the string $string.
     * 
     * @param \Twig_Environment $environment
     * @param array $context
     * @param string $string
     * @return string 
     */
    protected function parseString( \Twig_Environment $environment, $context, $string ) {
        $environment->setLoader( new \Twig_Loader_String( ) );
        return $environment->render( $string, $context );
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of this extension.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName( ) {
        return 'evaluate';
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
$twig_environment->addExtension( new EvaluateExtension( ) );
```

Use it in the template:

```
{% set var = 'inner variable' %}
{{'this is a string with an {{var}}'|evaluate}}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I needed to use this doc to properly add the extension http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html