# Interpret variable inside another

Tags: twig

I am trying to interpret a variable inside another. Something like:

```
// list of variables

foo: 'test';
bar: 'this is {{ foo }}'
```

```
// Twig

{{ bar }}

// result :

this is a test
```

I try this but I think it is old : [Twig variables in twig variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945200/twig-variables-in-twig-variable/10945264#comment117517386_10945264)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [template_from_string](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/template_from_string.html) Twig function.

```
{% set foo = 'test' %}
{{ include(template_from_string('this is {{ foo }}')) }}
```

The template will render with the context of the containing template, meaning, it will have access to all variables that the main template has access to.

Note that `template_from_string` Twig function is not available by default. It only becomes available once you activate `Twig\Extension\StringLoaderExtension` extension found in Twig package.